# How to open site written on localhost on mobile

Tags: localhost

I am trying to open site that I have written on localhost using my mobile. After typing my ip address followed by the port number I cannot connect - `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. However If I do the same on computer it immediately display my WordPress page. Any guess?

To be more specific - If I type only ip address - I obtain only xampp server site. If, after the ip address I add `/wordpress` I get this error.

Comment: I'd guess WordPress is triggering a redirect then to something that's not reachable remotely. What's are the WordPress address and Site address under Settings, General? Are they reachable remotely?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it's hard to guess. Many factors are at play, such as your network settings or your machine's settings, and settings vary depending on your operating system. Xampp could be a bit complex to set up and make it work across the network.

I suggest that you go with a very easy environment so you can focus more on the development of your site.

Try [`Local`](https://localwp.com/),it's very easy to install and doesn't require too much manual configuration. And, it has live links features, which give you or anyone access to your local site over the internet. You can use this to access your site using your mobile.